# Turn on WireGuard VPN when launching certain apps with Tasker

Tags: applications, tasker, automation, vpn

I'm having some trouble setting up a Tasker profile to enable Wireguard VPN when launching specific apps on Android. I created a profile and added the "STATE" option where it checks if the VPN is on, but I'm not sure how to make it detect when an app is launched. Basically need:

- If X app is launched
- Then check if VPN is on, if not turn it on.
- If it VPN fails to connect, throw a message. (optional)